# requirejs - How to structure app when initialization is needed with server generated values

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, commonjs

I'm interested in the best approach to how to structure a RequireJS-based project if some modules require init data generated dynamically in the page.

To clarify, my question, I would need to have somewhere in the main html page something like this:

```
/* Following lines generated on server side so need to be in the html page*/
var initDataForModule1= [ data, generated, by, server];
var initDataForModule1= [ some, other, data, generated, by, server];
```

Then, I would have some code that would require that data to completely set up the UI (not neccesarely to be loaded). For example, they would need to contain something like:

```
for(var i=0;i<initDataForModule1.length;i++)
     generateUIElementWithData(initDataForModule1[i]);
```

So, should I put the UI-setup code above in a module and then somehow load it and give it the init date? Or which would be a good aproach? I was thinking of something like:

```
<script src="/js/lib/require.js"></script>
<script>
    var initDataForModule1= [ data, generated, by, server];
    var initDataForModule1= [ some, other, data, generated, by, server];

    require(['module1'], function(module1){
       module1.initWithData(initDataForModule1);
    });

    ...
<script>
```

Also, which would be a good place to put my `requirejs.config()` part?

Answer (score 1):

Rendering JavaScript from server-side is asking for trouble: mixing languages makes it nearly impossible to refactor as you'll end up with templating tags in your JS files (that will also flag up during validation/linting). It would also couple your front- and back-end code, making the project less portable.

---

I decided to use the ["text" plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) which makes an AJAX call and reads config at runtime *(you'll need to remember to set `inlineText` to `false` in your r.js buildconfig file)*, for example:

```js
require(['main', 'someDep', 'text!../ajax/config'],
        function(App, someDep, configString) {
    App.start(dep, JSON.parse(configString);
});
```

Where `"../ajax/config"` is the path to a URL that serves the config in JSON format(*).

(*) There is also the [JSON plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins) but I couldn't get it to work and parsing JSON text "manually" wasn't much of a hassle for me.

Comment: Hm...there are definite disadvantages to this, though. It adds some server complexity (and some Javascript complexity) and increases the number of requests you need to make. The only scripts that need to include templating tags are the short ones rendered inside the HTML, which would only need to define a few configuration variables.

Comment: Regarding the mixing languages, how else can I do it? I didn't say I would put templating tags in the JS, but in the html file, so I would need some inline JS in the main page. I have some values computed on the server and I need to show them to the clients, but they require some JS for display. What could be an altenative?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the configuration. But I still have no idea how to avoid mixing languages or how to make structure it properly, so any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!